# Understanding the definition of limit of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm stuck trying to understand the equivalence of this two definitions of a limit which may textbook gives:

First if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = A$, then

$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0\quad \exists \delta >0 : 0<|x-a|< \delta \to |f(x) -A |< \varepsilon$$

Then it gives the definition in terms of neighborhoods:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0\quad \exists \delta >0 : \forall x \in \mathring{U}_{\delta}(a) \to f(x)\in U_{\varepsilon}(A)$$

It may be obvious, but I'm not getting why in the second definition we are including the point $A$. I mean

If $U_{\epsilon}(A) = [A-\varepsilon, A + \varepsilon]$ then by the first definition we'd have that:

$$0<|x-a|<\delta \to |f(x) -A | \leq \varepsilon$$

instead of

$$0<|x-a|<\delta \to |f(x) -A | < \varepsilon$$

They are still equivalent. What am I missing?

And also,

can we say $0<|x-a|\leq \delta$ instead of $0<|x-a|< \delta$ ?

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ (which is what you wrote) or $\lim_{x\to a}$ (which is what the description after the formula suggests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's wrong is the almost top line, you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}$ don't you

Anyway, in the second definition, $A$ plays the same role for $f(x)$ as does $a$ for $x$.

About the $<$ or $\leq$ issue, because of every metric space's great properties, which of course hold for $\mathbb{R}$ (every closed ball or interval with nonzero radius contains an open one, and vice-versa), you can do as you please. However, in purely topological contexts, convergence is defined in terms of open sets, and having strict inequalities better emphasises that.

More pragmatically, if you can fit everyone into the closed neighbourhood of A with radius $\varepsilon$ for some $\delta$, and if you can also fit everyone into the closed neighbourhood of radius $\varepsilon /2$  with a smaller $\delta$ then with the smaller $\delta$ you have fitted everyone into the OPEN neighbourhood around $A$ with radius $\varepsilon$.

So yes, you can equivalently interchange $<$ and $\leq$ for $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$, when denoting neighbourhoods (balls). Where you CANNOT mess about is for $\delta > 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Indeed $\delta$ has to be found strictly positive to prove continuity. As for $ \varepsilon$, it suffices that you fit everyone into nonzero radius balls to prove continuity. So replacing $\varepsilon > 0$ for $\varepsilon \geq 0$ in the definition would result in that a function be continuous at point $a$ if and only if it is constant on some neighbourhood of $a$, which would be stupidly assigning the term "continuity" to a concept which already bears the name of " local constantness" or "local constancy" or whatever  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I claim the following two statements are equivalent:

1. If $\epsilon > 0$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < | x - a | < \delta$ then $| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$.
2. If $\epsilon > 0$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < | x - a | < \delta$ then $| f(x) - L | \leq \epsilon$.

Proof: Clearly statement 1 implies statement 2.  We must only show that statement 2 implies statement 1.

So, assume that statement 2 is true.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  It follows from statement 2 that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < | x - a | < \delta$ then $| f(x) - L | \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  Thus, if $0 < | x - a | < \delta$ then $| f(x) - L | \leq \epsilon$.  So statement 1 is true.